# How to pass 2d array of any type

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

```
int main(void) {
    int no, flimit, i, pos_of_fval, freq_of_fval, n, j;
    long long int max;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &flimit);
    char list[n][21];
    long long int fval[n];
    char disp[flimit][21];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%s  %lld", list[i], &fval[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < flimit; i++) {
        max = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (fval[j] > max) {
                max = fval[j];
                pos_of_fval = j;
            }
        freq_of_fval = freq(fval, max, n);
        if (freq_of_fval == 1) {
            strcpy(disp[i], list[pos_of_fval]);
            fval[pos_of_fval] = 0;
        } else
            lexical(list, disp, fval, i, n, freq_of_fval, max);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < flimit; i++)
       printf("%s\n", disp[i]);

    return 0;
}

int freq(long long fval[], long long max, int n) {
    int count = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (fval[i] == max)
    count++;
    return count;
}

void lexical(char list[][21], char disp[][21], long long fval[],
             intn dispos ,intn, int freq_of_fval, long long max) {

    int a[freq_of_fval], i, j, apos = 0, temp;

    for (j = 0; j < freq_of_fval; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (fval[i] == max)
                a[apos++] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < freq_of_fval - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < freq_of_fval - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (strcmp((list[a[j]]), list[a[j + 1]]) > 1) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    strcpy(disp[dispos], list[a[0]]);
}
```

Error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'lexical' from incompatible pointer type
lexical(list,disp,fval,i,n,freq_of_fval,max);  
            note: expected 'char \*' but argument is of type 'char (\*)[21]'
     void lexical(char list[],char disp[][21],long long fval[], int dispos, int
```

Comment: First welcome to StackOverflow! Second you should provide a [mcve]... And third just throwing code and an error is not considered to be a good question here :)

Comment: *void lexical(char list[][21],char disp[][21],long long fval[],* `intn` *dispos,* `intn` *,int freq_of_fval,long long max)* -- Really??

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to the wonderful world of C coding - where you really need to keep a tight reign on your array length.

There are several issues with this code-
first of all, you are declaring arrays with unknown sizes. for example in -

```
char list[n][21];
```

A line like this can only work in C99 - otherwise you cant declare an array with variable size.
But even in the cases you can do that - in your case, n was never set before you used it.

Generally, in C - You have to options:
1. you know your array size in advance, and then you use that in both the allocation and in the function signature

For example, if you have 20x21 matrix, than in main code:

```
char list[20][21]
```

and then in the function

```
void lexical(char list[20][21],...)
```

or

```
void lexical(charlist[][],...)
```

2. if you don't know the size in advance, then you can allocate memory using malloc

in your main code:

```
//N is how many rows you have
char **list  = malloc(sizeof (char *) * N);
if (list  )
{
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 21);
  }
}
```

and then in the funciton:
    void lexical(char **list,...)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void lexical(char list[][21], char disp[][21], long long fval[],
             int dispos ,int n, int freq_of_fval, long long max);
int freq(long long fval[], long long max, int n) ;

int main(void) {

    int no, flimit, i, pos_of_fval, freq_of_fval, n, j;
    long long int max;

    printf("请输入n 和 flimit\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &flimit);

    char list[n][21];
    long long int fval[n];
    char disp[flimit][21];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        printf("字符串 和 long long数据\n");
        scanf("%s  %lld", list[i], &fval[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < flimit; i++) {

        max = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (fval[j] > max) {
                max = fval[j];
                pos_of_fval = j;
            }
        }

        freq_of_fval = freq(fval, max, n);

        if (freq_of_fval == 1) {
            strcpy(disp[i], list[pos_of_fval]);
            fval[pos_of_fval] = 0;
        } else {
            lexical(list, disp, fval, i, n, freq_of_fval, max);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < flimit; i++)
        printf("%s\n", disp[i]);

    return 0;
}

// 计算数组中最大值有多少个(相同的最大值)
int freq(long long fval[], long long max, int n) {

    int count = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (fval[i] == max)
            count++;
    return count;
}

void lexical(char list[][21], char disp[][21], long long fval[],
             int dispos ,int n, int freq_of_fval, long long max) {

    int a[freq_of_fval], i, j, apos = 0, temp;

    for (j = 0; j < freq_of_fval; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (fval[i] == max)
                a[apos++] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < freq_of_fval - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < freq_of_fval - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (strcmp((list[a[j]]), list[a[j + 1]]) > 1) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    strcpy(disp[dispos], list[a[0]]);
}
```